# Why is this random generator not working?

Tags: c++, function, random

Every time I run this code it returns this value: 1804289383
If I move the body of random() inside main() it runs just fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int random(int);

int main()
{

    cout << random();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

int random(int) 
{
    unsigned seed = time(0); 
    srand(seed);              

    int randomNum = rand()%4 + 1;
    return randomNum;
}
```

Comment: First of all: `int random(int);` is incompatible with your function call `random()` and your implementation doesn't implement a parameter.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and you will see the problem.

Comment: [http://xkcd.com/221/](http://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: You are seeding every time you call `random()` too. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `random()` expects an argument, and you're not supplying the argument.

If you call it like so:

```
cout << random(0);
```

it'll work.

A better approach, however, would be to eliminate the argument since it's unused.

Last but not least, you should only call `srand()` once, on program startup.

Comment: Wouldn't you then expect a compilation error rather than wrong build output? How does this explain the weird output?

Comment: but if I get rid of the argument it marks a compilation error saying, "new declaration 'int random()' ambiguates old declaration 'long int random()'"

Comment: You need to fix your prototype as well as your implementation.